# select2-4.0.3 displaying values as keys in JSON data

Tags: json, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

i have this JSON data coming from server. which is valid JSON per JASONlint

issue is when i enter 3 digits (anything bogus) I get the drop down, and it shows "keys" as values!!! I do not know why it is in reverse order??? if i use .each in place of .map it correctly lists values as values (in console log), but then shows nothing in dropdown (some error in select2 js is reported).

JSON: (firebug)

```
{"4":"2013","3":"2014","1":"2016","6":"winter","7":"birthday","2":"2015","5":"summer","8":"vacation"
}
```

this is my JS:

```
$("#selectTags").select2({
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    //closeOnSelect: false,
    tokenSeparators: ',',       //  [' ',','],
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "/cgi-bin/json-data.pl",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 100,
        data: function (params) {
            var queryParameters = {
                term: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (key,value) {
                    console.log('key='+key);
                    return {
                        id: key,
                        text: value
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with `map`, you have mixed up arguments, the first is value, the second is key.
see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/#jQuery-map-object-callback

```
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (value, key) {
                console.log('key='+key);
                return {
                    id: key,
                    text: value
                }
            })
        };
    }
```

Comment: i see. thank you, i realized that, but i did not know that it is the 'natural' assignment with .map (normally i would assume key before value).

Comment: it's because of ECMAScript5 Array.map's callback has first argument - value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So the similar signature is for objects to be compatible.

Comment: What if i have this sort of json.

Comment: "data": [
        {
            "4680": "0001 10 george street APPROACH ACACIA CREEK"
        },
        {
            "4677": "13 george street AMBLE ANULA"
        }
    ]